# Is there a simple method to check file changes in subfolders?

Tags: files, monitoring

Is there a simple method to check file changes in subfolders?

I have folder `SSLcerts` with subfolders `SiteNameXYZ`. Every subfolder consists pack of cert-files.

Ideally, I need a script that will respond to file changes (date modification) in any subfolder.

I don't want to attach `inotify` or systemd path-unit to every subfolder if possible. Because there are many subfolders and their number is dynamic.

If there is no simple solution - This is also the correct answer for me :)

Comment: You might just use `find` with `-exec stat` and write modification times next to file names in a table. Then regularly check this file against the current output. Maybe sorting and a nice `diff` will be more readable.

Comment: @FelixJS then _polling_, OP expect IMHO a smarted solution

Comment: Did you consider enhancing the program that makes the changes to also post the info somewhere, or trigger some aciton etc?

Comment: @meuh Yes, it was plan B. Not universal, not elegant, but in theory working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need immediate action on change in the directory - you would have to use `inotify`. And yes, each subdir in the tree would require its own watch.
But the number of watches would not be a real problem. Just scan the main directory on the start, for each subdir create a new watch, dive into that subdir and repeat. That recursion will give you all watches you need. And on directory creation/removal you can also create/remove watches.

If you are satisfied with a delayed check - you can do something like

```
#!/usr/sh

CUR=list_of_files.txt
PREV=old_list_of_files.txt
CHANGES=list_of_changes.txt

mv $CUR $OLD
ls -lR /maindir/ > $CUR
diff $OLD $CUR > $CHANGES

# And now you can do whatever you need with the changes.
```

Such script can be put into `cron` for a regular run.